# "fatal: failed to open database" error when starting Geth

Tags: go-ethereum

I am trying to create private block chain. When I am trying to run this command:

`geth init ./customgenesis.json`

...it is showing an error:

`fatal: failed to open database: The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process`

I am unable to proceed with the other steps. May I know how to overcome this?

Comment: Hi there. Do you already have another instance of Geth running on your machine? (Which platform are you on? Windows, OSX, Linux?) Are you following a particular tutorial?

Comment: Hi It's Windows.

Comment: Before you run `geth init` with your new genesis file, check whether there's an instance of Geth already running in Task Manager. Either that, or the editor you used to create the file might have a lock on it.

Comment: maybe you have a geth instance already running, kill then the previous one and restart geth

Answer (score 1):

This error will almost certainly be due to another Geth instance running in the background. This previous process will have already locked various files that any subsequent instances would require.

On Linux, check the output of `ps faux | grep geth`, find the process's ID, then kill it using `kill -INT <pid>`.

On Windows, check the output of Process Manager (or whatever it's actually called), and safely kill any Geth instance that is there.